# update data using jQuery - MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC application and I have a `ActionLink` for `edit` which turns the specific row into textboxes and `save` `ActionLink` appears instead of `Edit` on that row, but when I make changes and click on `save` data isn't saved in database, I just see the old data.

jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function toggleEditability() {
            $(this).closest('tr')
                   .find('a.Edit, a.Save, .displayText, input[type=text]')
                   .toggle(); 
        }

        $('a.Edit').click(toggleEditability);

        $('a.Save').click(function () {
            toggleEditability.call(this);
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).load(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

chtml Code:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            @*<th>
                @Html.Label("ID")
            </th>*@
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Description")
            </th>
            <th>
                 @Html.Label("Date")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(item.Holiday_date).Year.ToString() == DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
        {
            <tr>
           @* <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
                </div>
            </td>*@
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "Edit", Href="#" })
               @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Save", new { id = item.Holiday_Id}, new { @class = "Save", Href = "#", style = "display:none" } ) |
               @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkDelete" })
               @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Cancel", new { id = item.Holiday_Id}, new { @class = "Cancel", Href = "#", style = "display:none" } )
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    }

    </table>
```

Controller Code for edit:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist = db.tbl_HolidayList.Find(id);
            if (tbl_holidaylist == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return PartialView(tbl_holidaylist);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Holiday/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(tbl_HolidayList tbl_holidaylist)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tbl_holidaylist).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["Msg"] = "Data has been updated succeessfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return PartialView(tbl_holidaylist);
        }
```

Can anyone tell me where I am mistaking or where I have to make changes??

Comment: You are making a `GET` request to the server using `.load`. That will not send any changes. You need to send the changes instead using an `$.ajax` `POST` request (with the appropriate `data` property sent along with it).

Comment: can you kindly mention where and how do I make changes?

Comment: Example added below to head you in the right direction, but may not match your exact requirements.

Comment: You also needed to get your form working without the Ajax stuff first. If you check my update you will see why the form will not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment: You are making a `GET` request to the server using `.load`. That will not send any changes. You need to send the changes instead using an `$.ajax` `POST` request (with the appropriate `data` property sent along with it).

e.g. something like this (not exact, but give you the idea):

```
    $('a.Save').click(function () {
        toggleEditability.call(this);
        // Remember the element clicked
        var $element  $(this);
        // Get all the data from the nearest form
        var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        // Get the URL from the form
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,             // Url to send request to
            data: data,           // Send the data to the server
            type: "POST",         // Make it a POST request
            dataType: "html",     // Expect back HTML
            success: function(html){
                $(element).html(html);       // On success put the HTML "somewhere" (not sure where at this point)
            });
        });
    });
```

Another problem is with your view. You cannot render a form with repeated items using a `foreach` loop. That does not provide enough information for the `EditorFor` type methods to render an index (which allows it to name the items uniquely) . You need to use a simple `for` loop:

**e.g.**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Mode.Length; i++){
  {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Holiday_Id, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
       [snip]
  }
```

Comment: I made that changes according to me requirements but `null` is going in my controller method.

Comment: Your example pages are incomplete. Can you make sure the entire view is shown and the `tbl_HolidayList` class?

Comment: This is my `tbl_HolidayList` class and its working fine, but the data is going null in edit method
`public partial class tbl_HolidayList
    {
        public int Holiday_Id { get; set; }
        public string Holiday_Name { get; set; }
        public string Holiday_Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Holiday_date { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: You need to update your question with that information *and* the full view cshtml page. Comments are pretty useless for code and I need to see the entire problem to  figure out why your passed data is coming though as null (might need to create a repro). Thanks.

Comment: I updated this problem as a new question, kindly check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782782/data-is-not-going-in-controller-method-mvc